GNU `make`, modification times, leap seconds and NTP
GNU make relies on timestamps to see if a dependency was changed after some file was built. If you make a change during the leap second or an NTP adjustment, is it possible that make will believe the dependency is older than the built file when it really isn't? This would cause the file to never be rebuilt.

UNIX timestamps are not saved as dates and daytimes, but as monotonous counters since begin of the UNIX epoch 1970-01-01 00:00:00¹.
Therefore, that problem does not arise.

¹ not exactly though, there's been leap-second-adjustments… it's a long, quite ugly story. However, takeaway is that file time stamps increase monotonically with time. By the way, it looks like there will never by leap seconds again.

I know the timestamps are usually monotonically increasing, but the question is about the possible exceptions: NTP adjustments and leap seconds.

and I answered that: still monotonous; leap seconds don't affect how many seconds have happened since some point in time. They affect how that number of passed seconds is converted to a human-readable datetime. . (unless your NTP client does things it shouldn't do. Modern NTP clients by default are safe, in that they never set the clock back, they just "slow down" time, so that timestamps remain monotonous)

OK so that answers the part about NTP, what about leap seconds (if there are more)? Are timestamps in TAI rather than in Unix time?

They are not a problem at all, as they don't affect the time that has passed since epoch in any way differently than any other second. Leap seconds are a "converting time stamps to human-readable time" issue, not a time issue. Physics don't care.

But we're not talking about physics, we're talking about Unix timestamps... Sorry if I'm being obtuse but talking about time in physics doesn't resolve the question. Is the answer that timestamps in the filesystem are stored as a TAI offset rather than a UTC offset?

unix timestamps are a counter that keeps increasing by 1 every second. Whether some humans declare that second a leap second or not doesn't matter to UNIX time.

I believe that is false. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time "It measures time by the number of non-leap seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970"

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758932/unix-time-leap-seconds-and-converting-unix-time-to-a-date/758936#758936

the counter increases once per second, full stop; Leap seconds shift the reference point (epoch isn't anymore necessarily at exactly 00:00 on the first of January 1970).

Hmm but if the reference point gets shifted forwards, the counter is going to decrease, which contradicts your claim it never decreases.

no, it really doesn't. The counter is monotonous, it increases by 1 per second. That's the definition.

Well the Wikipedia link I posted seems to disagree with you, it even has a table demonstrating an example of Unix time decreasing during leap second, so either your answer is incorrect or Wikipedia is very wrong about Unix time.

you might want to read the other answer on the question I linked to. If wikipedia contradicts that, wikipedia is wrong (or your interpretation of it).

A simple experiment confirms for me that you are definitely wrong: https://time.is/Unix_time shows that Unix time modulo 60 matches the current time in seconds in UTC. Python's time.time() function also matches that.

have you really read the other answer? I ask that because this confusion between "decomposed UNIX time" and "UTC" in the presence in leap seconds is explicitly addressed in there.

Sorry but your other answer clearly is wrong in light of the fact that Unix time jumps by 1 second during a leap second, as described on Wikipedia, and as I just confirmed by experiment.
